# Receive telmetry from IoT hub on Android with Event Hub .for particular Device in IOT HUB

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, iot, azure-eventhub

On Xamarin Android, I am using Event Hub for receiving data from IoT Hub. How can we receive data from a particular device?

For example, if we have `device001` and `device002`, I want to receive telemetry from IoT hub for only `device001` and telemetry from IoT hub for only `device002` using Event Hub, or is there any other way?

Comment: How many devices are we talking about? And why do you need this?

Comment: Every Mobile is an Device in IOT Hub..When Data in device is Updated.The Mobile App has to notified.

Comment: I believe that your question needs more details in order for us to give you a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Event hubs don't support filtering as for example Service Bus queues or subscriptions.

You can receive all the events of one given partition (using `EventHubConsumerGroup.CreateReceiver`). Further filtering to device level will have to happen in your code. If you have many devices per partition, you might want to have some intermediate service that filters events before they get to the mobile device (e.g. a web app with SignalR).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail,Is there any other way for getting events of only that device.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider message routing capability of IoT Hub. There is a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153543/azure-iothub-devicemessage-structure-and-route-query)

Which leads also to [here (good discussion)](https://blog.jongallant.com/2016/12/azure-iot-hub-routes/)

In any case, you could you Azure Functions to listen and filter messages, route to almost wherever you want. [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/) are serverless hence low cost coding service. It has quick integration capabilities through UI with click click but requires some coding knowledge.