# Azure IoTHub DeviceMessage structure and route query

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

I used the python example from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-python to send telemetry data to the IoTHub. Now I try to forward only the messages from the device "test-device" into a blob storage via a custom endpoint and a route. With the query string "true" all messages from all devices are pushed to the storage. However, I don't get the query to select only the messages from the deviceId "test-device". I search in the documentation but didn't find any helpful example...

Can anyone help me with the query? At least it would be also helpful to sample incoming messages inside the IoTHub to get an idea of the structure of IotHub messages (like it is done in the StreamAnalytics "sample data").

Comment: hi, I have a bit similar problem. Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `$connectionDeviceId = "{your device id}"` in the route query. `connectionDeviceId` is stamped on servicebound messages by the IoT Hub. I think it is simpler than silent's suggestion. Message system properties are prefixed with the '$' symbol. More query language for message routing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#get-started-with-device-to-cloud-message-routes-query-expressions).

Comment: I also tried this, but it doesen't work for me. If I dump everything into the blob (routing with 'true') I see the property `connectionDeviceID` but somehow the route ignores it...

Comment: @Juppo, i have tested this query string, it works fine. Did you add the quotes for the device or did you check that the device is right? Please note that the query string is case-sensitive.

Comment: I checked again the spelling and tested it with single and double quotes. I also updated all libraries and somehow it works magically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax
**connectionDeviceId** This value is set by IoT Hub and identifies the source of the messages. This could be device telemetry messages, device twin change notifications, or device lifecycle events. **This cannot be queried.**

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good blog post on message routing [here](https://blog.jongallant.com/2016/12/azure-iot-hub-routes/).

You can for example route on any properties you add to your messages or on any field inside your message body (if it is UTF-8 encoded JSON). Not sure if you can by default route on deviceId, but you could for example add a property `"testmessage": true` to your messages and then have a routing rule to match that:
`"testmessage" = true`